# Two tables on one page

Tags: tables

I am trying to get two tables on one horizontal page. I have looked around here and tried many of the suggested solutions but it does not seem to want to go where it should. I think mostly because the caption is very broad. Can anyone see if this is combinable?

```
\afterpage{\clearpage
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|l|}
\hline
$\lambda_\mathrm{d}$ [\AA] & $\sigma(\lambda_\mathrm{d})$  [\AA]& $\lambda_\mathrm{f}$  [\AA]& $\sigma(\lambda_\mathrm{f})$  [\AA]& Ion\\ 
\hline\hline
6280.6264 &0.0022  &6280.6245  &0.0026  &Fe\,{\sc\i}\\
6285.1676 &0.0018 &6285.1670 &0.0032  &V\,{\sc\i}\\
6290.5479 &0.0023 &6290.5486 &0.0050 &Fe\,{\sc\i}\\
6290.9722 &0.0019 &6290.9719 &0.0025 &Fe\,{\sc\i}\\
6292.8325 &0.0031 &6292.8324 &0.0049  &V\,{\sc\i} \\
6293.9267 &0.0017 &6293.9270 &0.0040 &Fe\,{\sc\i}\\
6296.4985 &0.0021 &6296.4964 &0.0035  &V\,{\sc\i} \\
6297.8021 &0.0023 &6297.8005 &0.0022 &Fe\,{\sc\i} \\
6300.3237 &0.0025 &6300.3203 &0.0053  &O\,{\sc\i} \\
6300.6830 &0.0033 &6300.6838 &0.0036 &Sc\,{\sc ii} \\
6301.5115 &0.0024 &6301.5108 &0.0025 &Fe\,{\sc\i} \\
6302.5026 &0.0017 &6302.5012 &0.0027 &Fe\,{\sc\i} \\
6303.4638 &0.0017 &6303.4648 &0.0045 &Fe\,{\sc\i} \\
6303.7613 &0.0019 &6303.7625 &0.0039 &Ti\,{\sc\i} \\
6304.3374 &0.0025 &6304.3364 &0.0052 &Zr\,{\sc\i}\\
6305.6660 &0.0059 &6305.6766 &0.0124 &Sc\,{\sc\i} \\
6306.2029 &0.0040 &6306.2080 &0.0066 &Fe\,{\sc i}\\
6307.8559 &0.0030 &6307.8561 &0.0063 &Fe\,{\sc i} \\
6309.8823 &0.0025 &6309.8791 &0.0078 &Sc\,{\sc ii}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Solar lines in the wavelength region considered in this lab \citep{Allende_Garcia_1998}. Use this table for line identification. $\lambda_\mathrm{d}$ is the central wavelength in the disc-centre spectrum with corresponding standard deviation $\sigma(\lambda_\mathrm{d})$, while $\lambda_\mathrm{f}$ is the central wavelength in the flux spectrum with standard deviation $\sigma(\lambda_\mathrm{f})$. Note that these are wavelengths in air. The last column shows the chemical element and ionisation state.}
\label{tab:solar_lines}



\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
$\lambda_\mathrm{tell}$ [\AA] \\ 
\hline\hline
6287.749\\
6289.398\\
6290.221\\
6292.162\\
6292.958\\
6295.178\\
6295.960\\
6298.457\\
6299.228\\
6302.000\\
6302.764\\
6305.810\\
6306.565\\
6309.886\\
6310.636\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Telluric O$_2$ lines (air wavelengths) by \citet{Moore_etal_1966}.}
\label{tab:telluric_lines}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
}
```

Comment: Sure, the tables are "combinable", i.e., they could be placed one next to the other. The bigger question is, how will this be taken by the readers. The first table has 19 rows, the second only 15. Placing them side-by-side is going to be ugly. What's the connection between the tables?

Comment: They are both used for reference. If there is a cm between the two then it should be fine right? Especially if its on a landscape page.

Comment: well a cm distance between em would be a good start. just to be sure though i would place a vertical line inbetween the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some comments and suggestions:

- I suggest you place the two `tabular` environments and their associated `\caption` and `\label` statements in separate `minipage` environments. As one table has four more rows than the other, as well as a much longer legend, it's going to be well-nigh impossible to make them look "natural" if they're displayed side by side.
- Don't allow empty lines between the `minipage` environments, as empty lines trigger paragraph breaks.
- Consider using the `\ce` macro (provided by the `mhchem` package) for typesetting chemical formulas and the `\si` macro (provided by the `siunitx` package) for typesetting scientific units.
- As far as I can tell, there's no need to use landscape mode to typeset the `table` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,mhchem,natbib,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{minipage}[t]{8.1cm}  % width determined by trial and error
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccl@{}}
\toprule
$\lambda_\mathrm{d}$ [\si{\angstrom}] & 
$\sigma(\lambda_\mathrm{d})$  [\si{\angstrom}]& 
$\lambda_\mathrm{f}$ [\si{\angstrom}] & 
$\sigma(\lambda_\mathrm{f})$  [\si{\angstrom}]& 
Ion\\ 
\midrule
6280.6264 &0.0022 &6280.6245 &0.0026 &\ce{Fe^{I}} \\
6285.1676 &0.0018 &6285.1670 &0.0032 &\ce{V^{I}}  \\
6290.5479 &0.0023 &6290.5486 &0.0050 &\ce{Fe^{I}} \\
6290.9722 &0.0019 &6290.9719 &0.0025 &\ce{Fe^{I}} \\
6292.8325 &0.0031 &6292.8324 &0.0049 &\ce{V^{I}}  \\ 
\addlinespace
6293.9267 &0.0017 &6293.9270 &0.0040 &\ce{Fe^{I}} \\
6296.4985 &0.0021 &6296.4964 &0.0035 &\ce{V^{I}}  \\
6297.8021 &0.0023 &6297.8005 &0.0022 &\ce{Fe^{I}} \\
6300.3237 &0.0025 &6300.3203 &0.0053 &\ce{O^{I}}  \\
6300.6830 &0.0033 &6300.6838 &0.0036 &\ce{Sc^{II}}\\
\addlinespace
6301.5115 &0.0024 &6301.5108 &0.0025 &\ce{Fe^{I}} \\
6302.5026 &0.0017 &6302.5012 &0.0027 &\ce{Fe^{I}} \\
6303.4638 &0.0017 &6303.4648 &0.0045 &\ce{Fe^{I}} \\
6303.7613 &0.0019 &6303.7625 &0.0039 &\ce{Ti^{I}} \\
6304.3374 &0.0025 &6304.3364 &0.0052 &\ce{Zr^{I}} \\
\addlinespace
6305.6660 &0.0059 &6305.6766 &0.0124 &\ce{Sc^{I}} \\
6306.2029 &0.0040 &6306.2080 &0.0066 &\ce{Fe^{I}} \\
6307.8559 &0.0030 &6307.8561 &0.0063 &\ce{Fe^{I}} \\
6309.8823 &0.0025 &6309.8791 &0.0078 &\ce{Sc^{II}}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Solar lines in the wavelength region considered in 
this lab \citep{Allende_Garcia_1998}.} 
\label{tab:solar_lines}

\medskip\small
Use this table for line identification. $\lambda_\mathrm{d}$ 
is the central wavelength in the disc-centre spectrum with 
corresponding standard deviation $\sigma(\lambda_\mathrm{d})$, 
while $\lambda_\mathrm{f}$ is the central wavelength in the 
flux spectrum with standard deviation $\sigma(\lambda_\mathrm{f})$. 
Note that these are wavelengths in air. The last column shows 
the chemical element and ionisation state.
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{10mm} % horizontal separation
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.8cm}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
\toprule
$\lambda_\mathrm{tell}$ [\si{\angstrom}] \\ 
\midrule
6287.749\\
6289.398\\
6290.221\\
6292.162\\
6292.958\\
\addlinespace
6295.178\\
6295.960\\
6298.457\\
6299.228\\
6302.000\\
\addlinespace
6302.764\\
6305.810\\
6306.565\\
6309.886\\
6310.636\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Telluric \ce{O2} lines (air wavelengths) \citep{Moore_etal_1966}.}
\label{tab:telluric_lines}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```